# Is there a general formula for the partial sum of an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

For the infinite series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-1}$ , the partial sum $S_n$ is $$S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^2-1}=\frac{3n^2-n-2}{4n(n+1)}$$ I got this equation from wolfram alpha, but I want to know if there is a general method for computing the partial sum of an infinite series.

Comment: $$2=(n+1)-(n-1)$$ and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: I do not think that partial sums may always exist in closed form, even though the infinite summation may be determined as a number. For example, the series $\frac{1}{n^2}$ doesn't have partial sums as a closed form, but it's limit is known to be $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Of course, knowledge of partial sums in closed form is extremely helpful in knowing the infinite summation.

Comment: Of course you are asking for something far too powerful to belong to the human race, but there certainly is a general method for computing telescopic sums, i.e. to recognize they are telescopic sums.

Comment: *Creative telescoping* is a powerful technique arising from a simple idea: in practical cases, it is very likely that the general term of a sum/series is well-approximated by a telescopic term, and the approximation-by-objects-we-are-really-able-to-add trick can be reiterated. See the first section of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), for instance.

Comment: Since there is only a philosophical difference between *knowing a real number* and *knowing arbitrarily accurate approximations of a real number* creative telescoping can be seen as a practical method for computing sums/series.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k^2-1} = \sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{(k-1)(k+1)} = 
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(k+1) - (k-1)}{2(k-1)(k+1)} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=2}^n \Big\{ \ \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k+1}\Big\}
$$

**Hint**: Some of these negative terms will get cancelled with previous positive terms. So what are the terms we will be left with after all cancellations.

Comment: the does not ask for that particular sum